# Почему не выполняется вторая часть условия else if()?

Tags: javascript, if

```
<header>
 <nav>
   <button id="btn_toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
   </button>

   <div id="navbar_nav">
    <ul>
     <li>home</li>
     <li>home</li>
     <li>home</li>
     <li>home</li>
     <li>home</li>
     <li>home</li>
    </ul>
   </div>

</nav>
```

```
//код js в отдельном файле

    let nav_toggle = document.getElementById('btn_toggle');

    nav_toggle.onclick = function () {
        if(document.getElementById('navbar_nav').style.display = 'none') {
            document.getElementById('navbar_nav').style.display = 'flex';
        } else if (document.getElementById('navbar_nav').style.display = 'flex') {
            document.getElementById('navbar_nav').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Comment: проблема в `=` в условии, оператор сравнения это `==` или `===`

Comment: @Grundy, только одна из трёх.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не понял про что ты :)

Comment: @Grundy, в коде 3 ошибки: сравнение, способ получения стилей и неправильный элемент.

Comment: @Qwertiy элемент же правильный вроде?

Comment: @Grundy, ну стили он не привёл, но скорее всего flex нужен для расположения li в строку, а значит он висит на ul. Вешать на navbar_nav флекс я смысла не вижу, так что весьма вероятно, что элемент не тот.

Answer (score 2):

Причина такая же, как и в первом случае. У данного элемента нет данных в атрибуте `style`, которое вы запрашиваете. Ваше выражение типа`document.getElementById('navbar_nav').style.display` получает ответ "" (пустая строка).

Если хотите получить стили CSS, Вам необходимо использовать `window.getComputedStyle(element).display`. Подробнее про этот [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Также у Вас ошибка в условиях. Оператор "=" это присваивания, "==" - сравнение, "===" строгое сравнение без приведение типов.

Comment: #navbar_nav {
 display: none;
}

Comment: В стилях указано display: none. Всё как надо. При помощи jq могу это легко сделать , а вот в js проблемы, только изучаю)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сейчас попробую)

Comment: @Дима, это находится не в атрибуте "style". Попробуйте добавьте атрибут "style"

Comment: @Дима, jQuery использует getComputedStyle() :-)

Comment: .show()  .hide() .toggleClass всегда использовал эти функции в библиотеках jq, но сейчас стал учить js, и пытаюсь использовать его при верстке. Но только начал изучать полноценно этот язык, и многого еще не понимаю в нем.

Comment: Хочу обходится без сторонних библиотек

Comment: @Дима, правильно делаете. К тому же `jQuery` рекомендую использовать slim версию ( если есть потребность в использовании jQuery), а там отсутствуют функции анимации, ajax

Comment: А ещё он не на том элементе проверяет значение.

Comment: document.getElementById('btn_toggle').onclick = function() {
 openbox('navbar_nav'); 
};

function openbox(btn_toggle) {
 let div = document.getElementById(btn_toggle);
 if(div.style.display == 'block') {
  div.style.display = 'none';
 } else {
   div.style.display = 'block';
 }
}

Comment: Еще как вариант

Comment: @Дима не будет работать

Answer (score 1):

Пора уже давно перейти на `hidden`:

```js
document.getElementById('btn_toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('navbar_nav')
  el.hidden = !el.hidden
})
```

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}

#navbar_nav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar_nav li {
  padding: .25em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button id="btn_toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span></span>
  </button>

  <ul id="navbar_nav" hidden>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: магия какая!!!!

Comment: :-) :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Воодушевлённый ответом `Qwertiy` я сделал так (с плавным исчезновением).

```js
document.getElementById('btn_toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('navbar_nav')
  el.hidden = !el.hidden
})
```

```css
[hidden] {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#navbar_nav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#navbar_nav li {
  padding: .25em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button id="btn_toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span></span>
  </button>

  <ul id="navbar_nav" hidden>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Не надо так над атрибутом издеваться - он не для этого. К тому же, ты c `display` накосячил. Если хочется плавно, надо делать toggle класса своего. PS: `Qwerify` меня ещё не называли)

Comment: @Qwertiy что не так с `display`?

Comment: В браузерных стилях для него стоит `none`. Работает только из-за того, что в коде он переопределён на flex.

Comment: @Михаил Камахин, вставлю свои 5 копеек. Если хотите сделать максимально красиво, то при скрытие элемента я бы сделал `filter:opacity(0); position: absolute`, где анимация `position` срабатывает через `step-end`.

Comment: @Qwertiy  - понятно, что он вроде аналог `display: none`. Но как по мне ничего не мешает добавить анимацию, если проект этого требует. Можно конечно создать класс для этой цели FadeOut.

Comment: @Node_pro, он не аналог, а он именно для этого и создан, и даже стили для этого есть. `!important` не поставили только ради обратной совместимости, а по идее он там должен быть. Если надо другое скрытие, то логично переключать класс. А position вроде не анимируется, как и display?

Comment: Qwertiy, верно, однако "step-end" - тип анимации с задержкой. По сути мы делаем задержку этого действия